# How can I configure `anybody` to run X in a one-liner?

Tags: xorg, non-root-user

The common solution posted is to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common` which gives a graphical prompt, however, I'm wanting to use this non-interactively.

Scenario is that I'm SSH'd into a machine as root (during Vagrant provisioning) and need to run `startx` once as a regular user to generate some config files before proceeding to subsequent steps.

I believe the reason I cannot simply `su otheruser startx` is due to Xauthority/me being connected via SSH as another user...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I found was to run the following:

```
sudo sed -i \
    's/allowed_users=console/allowed_users=anybody/' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

**Note**, that in your situation, the `console` may be `root` or another, based on your particular initial configuration*

Comment: convincing X to drop root privileges is a rather new feature (`xorg 1.16.0` iirc). Details are found in `man Xorg.wrap`.

Comment: On debian the configuration file "Xwrapper.config" may be present, while the package xserver-xorg-legacy is not installed. In this case it has no effect, so the problems persist after changing the configuration.